# Is it possible to sort files by extension in a Visual Studio project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a big solution to developp which includes several projects. I would like if possible to sort items in those projects by type (Dataset together, ".cs" files together etc.). Visual studio sort file by alphabetical order so is it possible to modify the sort method and if yes, how ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

No You Cannot. Is it irrelevant to Sort by type?